# How to align accordingly an ImageView and a TextView in a custom ListView row?

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview

I have created a list view with a custom adapter and custom row layout that includes an ImageView and a TextView.

What my problem is, because of the views that are **programatically created at my app run time** this result comes up for ex:
[image]

*** *Black rectangles represent icons in each row***

The view that includes these views is Linear Layout and what I tried to do is to set gravity to center. It work. But when it comes to long titles **the Icon moves out the middle**.

How can I succeed the following result,with whatever title length comes on(No huge enough though)?

[image]

Thanks in advance!
My xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item_name"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post ur item xml

Comment: What do you mean by " **programmatically created** " ? Any `ListView` are generated to the list using an XML like the one you provided.
I guess icons has to be in a position that doesn't change (ex: beginning), and the text can go as far it needs. Centering the titles will always miss up icons position according to the title length
For the fact that the 2nd title is not correctly aligned means there's a problem in aligning list items, or maybe in their parent contraints

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible because the gravity of the linear layout is "**center**", you should change the gravity of this linear layout to be "**left**" and do any **margin** you want at the left of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Do That:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item_name"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Item_name"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `gravity` of `LinearLayout` to `left`, set up `layout_marginLeft` of `ImageView`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="left">
       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
```